# cakephp 1.1 with php 5.3

Tags: cakephp, deprecated, php

I have just upgraded from php 5.1 to 5.3 and had previously been using cakephp 1.1 on my server. Since the upgrade (or possibly earlier, I can't be sure), I'm getting the following errors. Can anyone shed some light:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/dispatcher.php on line 157

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/dispatcher.php on line 221

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/libs/controller/controller.php on line 308

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/libs/controller/controller.php on line 347

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/libs/controller/controller.php on line 535

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/libs/controller/controller.php on line 805

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/libs/controller/component.php on line 128

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/libs/view/view.php on line 686

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/libs/class_registry.php on line 55

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/libs/model/connection_manager.php on line 84

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/vhosts/bbblh.co.uk/httpdocs/cake/libs/model/connection_manager.php on line 107
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically what it says is: What you (cakephp in this case) are trying to do will still work in this version, but could be removed in future php versions.

You should upgrade cakephp to a newer version. You could also suppress the warnings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

but the danger in doing that is that you forget about it and your site stops working without warning the next time you upgrade php.

Comment: Seconded for upgrading Cake.  It's easy.

Comment: When you upgrade Cake core, be sure to check these out:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/411/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-1-to-1-2
 & 

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3

Comment: You did well if that's the only error you got! Cake v1.1 is ancient. UPGRADE!